# ¿ Como añadir espacio en blanco cada 4 caracteres a un input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usestate

De qué manera puedo añadir un espacio en blanco cada 4 caracteres al value de un input, ya lo estoy haciendo para actualizar un estado, la idea es formatear el número de una tarjeta de crédito/débito, lo hago de esta manera:

```
if (inputName == "cardNumber") {
    inputValue = inputValue.match(/.{1,4}/g);
    inputValue = inputValue?.join(" ");

    if (inputValue?.length > 19) {
        setCardNumberError("Card numbers must be only 16 characters");
        return;
    } else {
        setCardNumberError("");
    }
}
```

Y este es el resultado que puedo ver usando ese estado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver el número en la tarjeta, si introduce el espacio correctamente, pero si quiere usar el mismo estado en el value del input para que inserte también un espacio cada cuatro caracteres de manera automática. Pasa esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De qué manera puedo hacer que en ambas partes mantenga el mismo formato (un espacio cada 4 caracteres)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta función agrega un espacio a un string

```
const num = "1234456890";

let sp = Array.from(num).reduce((acc,t,i) => {
   if(i>0 && i%4==0) acc+=" "; //esta condición es la que hace el truco, tiene que ser divisible por 4 y mayor que cero, esto último para no agregar un espacio al inicio ya que cero es 0/4 es cero
   acc+=t;
   return acc;
});
```

En un input seria

```js
const addEspace = e => Array.from(e).reduce((acc,t,i) => {
   if(i>0 && i%4==0) acc+=" ";
   acc+=t;
   return acc;
});

const CreditOnInput = _ => event.target.value = addEspace(event.target.value.replaceAll(" ","")); 
//removemos los espacios que habiamos ingresado antes
```

```html
<input oninput="CreditOnInput()">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Sirve muy bien, aunque tuve que añadir una verificación para comprobar que la modificación que se le iba a hacer al input en la función CreditOnInput, no fuera un string vacío, ya que así asignaba el target (y el estado) como 'undefined'

Answer (score 2):

Tendrías que borrar todos los espacios con expresión regular y nuevamente generar 1 espacio en cada 4 caracteres en tu cadena (también con expresión regular). Agrego un `if` para que sólo agregue espacios cuando el valor del input es diferente a vacío, porque antes, al borrar todo de golpe, no permitía hacer `join(" ")` a un vacío (`null`). Aquí un ejemplo en un input:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("myInput");

input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  const inputValue = this.value.replace(/\s/g, ""); // quitamos todos los espacios encontrados...
  if (inputValue !== "") {
    const result = inputValue.match(/.{1,4}/g).join(" "); // y agregamos un espacio cada 4 caracteres, uso join(" ") para quitar las comas...
    this.value = result; // Y el valor del input será la cadena modificada.
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
```

y en un string:

```js
const numero = "1234567891011121";
const result = numero.match(/.{1,4}/g).join(" ");
console.log(result);
```